# Python showing timespan

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I created a chart where you can see the visualized data and the trend of the data. 
Is it possible to cut the chart on a timespan?

This is my code for the chart

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(True)
year = mdates.YearLocator(month=1)
month = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=3)
year_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')
month_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%m')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(month)
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which = 'minor')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(year)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(year_format)
plt.plot(df.index, df['JAN'], c='blue')
plt.plot(decomposition.trend.index, decomposition.trend, c='red')
```

[image]

I had this code to shorten the chart but I couldn´t figure out how to use it in the code above.

```
start_date = datetime(2004,1,1)
end_date = datetime(2008,1,1)
df[(start_date<=df.index) & (df.index<=end_date)].plot(grid='on')
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `plt.xlim([datetime(2004, 1, 1), datetime(2008, 1, 1)])`?

Comment: @WilliamMiller That worked. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Turned it into an answer so you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plt.xlim` to adjust the date range,

```py
plt.xlim([datetime(2004, 1, 1), datetime(2008, 1, 1)])
```

Which will give you an x-axis that looks like

[image]